# How can I make a background-image adjust to screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've created navigation and a section that has a background image and I want it to adjust automatically to screen size, however, it's not adjusting properly, the size of the `background-image` almost remains the same when resizing the browser window. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

How it looks normally
[image]

How it looks while resizing the browser window

[image]

The "DEVOUR" logo is not fully visible.
Please do not mind the navigation, I'll fix that later.

Link to the IMG - https://ctrlv.sk/mCXU

```css
/* GENERAL */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: black;

}

.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* HEADER AND NAV */

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgb(7, 7, 7);
    opacity: 80%;
    padding-left: 15em;
    padding-right: 12em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}

header:hover,
header:focus {
    opacity: 100%;
    transform:scale(1.05);;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

header:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 80%;
    transform:scale(1);
    transition: 1s ease;
    
}


nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item-first {
    color: #da2424;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin: 1em;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #da2424;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* FIRST SECTION */

.main-section {
    background-image: url('../IMG/main-section-logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 80vh;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
}

.main-section .button-container {
    height: 90%;
    display:  flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
      <header>
          <img src="IMG/straight-back-games-logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo of straight back games studio" width=110px>
          <nav class="navbar">
              <ul>
                  <li><a class="nav-item-first" href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a class="nav-item"  href="#">PRESS</a></li>
                  <li><a class="nav-item"  href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/1274570/DEVOUR/" target='_blank'>BUY DEVOUR!</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>
      </header>

      <section class="main-section">
          <div class="button-container">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="buttons">
                      <a href="#" class="btn-red">BUY NOW</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn-white">WATCH TRAILER</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </section>
```

Comment: See if this helps https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ the img selector won't have any effect on the background image. It's size is now controlled by the .main-section size and how it acts within that container is controlled by background css

Comment: I think the height on you .main-section is fine just be aware that it only covers 80% of the viewport height which leaves the width of your image open to interpretation because the size is on cover meaning once it have covered that 80vh it's done it's job

Comment: thank you, ive tried some of those tricks, unfortunately, it's only the "DEVOUR" logo that keeps on having this issue.. its still not fully visible.

Comment: So the css trick only works if you don't care about the width of your image. However you do,  so instead of cover your probably going to want to use 100vw (or whatever you want) for the background image size. Then place it in the center bottom so you keep the flame effect from the bottom. Then set the background color to black so the image stays put but the whole screen is black when the image runs out top to bottom. Does that make sense? I can give examples when I get home

Comment: Yeah, that would be the best as I am still struggling with it :D Thank you, I've edited my post and added a link to the image I am using.

Comment: Take a look at these docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size I'll get you when I get back to the house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the thing... the code below answers your question from earlier but I do not believe it solves your problem.

```
.main-section {
    background: url('main-section-logo.jpg') no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
}
```

What I believe what you want is this.. read the comments.. full explanation below

```css
.main-section {

/* full screen background image "fire in background" */

  background: url('bg-img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  /* height of this section 100% of the viewport height */
  
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* borders */
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
  
  /* align item "container" to center of page */
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- full screen section display grid for alignment -->

        <section class="main-section">
        
                <!-- contains bg-logo and buttons container -->
                
                <div class="container">
                
                    <!-- "background image" logo only -->
                    
                    <img class="background-logo" src="bg-logo.png" alt="">
                    
                    <!-- buttons -->
                    
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-red">BUY NOW</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-white">WATCH TRAILER</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

you need to split the background image into 2 parts so you can control them individually. Use the word DEVOUR as a regular image and set the max width on the container to limit the width (which you already did I just changed it from 1500px to 1000px)
then use a background image on the .main-section so that the fire is always behind the word DEVOUR.

If you want a working copy here is a link to the github repo I made for you, you can just download it (I grabbed a fire image off google I don't own that).

https://github.com/codeKJEK/split-bg-image

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Or read this page, can be usefull:

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: Tried it both with max-width: 100%; (which was default) and with width: 100%;, however it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Tip:

```
.main-section {
    background-image: url('../IMG/main-section-logo.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    height: 80vh;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(15, 13, 13);
}
```

Using height is not a good option at all. Try to avoid it.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the reply. I've added that to my IMG in CSS but unfortunately, the background image ("DEVOUR") still looks the same. And about the height, are there any other options that you can suggest to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a % when dealing with height/width of contents on a page if you would like them to be responsive, as adding in a % means that the size will not be static, and will respond to the size of the browser window/screen.

Try this in your CSS

```
img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the reply. I've added that to my IMG in CSS but unfortunately, the background image ("DEVOUR") still looks the same,

Comment: Hi, this could be because you are using the following syntax for your image: `width=110px>` . Remove that and replace it with `style="width: 100%;"`